# Android notification null pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null, notifications

I have a notification set up in an activity.  It creates the notification as expected.  When I go back to the Home screen, the notification is still up there, good.  If I click on the notification, it takes me back to the activity that created it, great.  If I click on a button to cancel the notification, I get a NullPointerException.

Here's the call:

```
if (notificationManager == null)
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, myClass.class);
Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.icon, getString(R.string.notify), System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(myClass.this, "AppName","Description", PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Here's the cancel:

```
private OnClickListener onClick_Buttons = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn:
                notificationManager.cancel(1);

                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:215)
    at com.myApp.myClass$2.onClick(myClass.java:281)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the stack trace in logcat?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Whats at ZygoteInit.java line 868?

Comment: I have no clue.  com.android.internal.os....  There's only 364 lines in my activity.

Comment: Sorry - didn't notice that. Looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html -Have you tried cancel all? Or have you tried keeping a handle on the notification object and "FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL" flag?

Comment: i have tried CancelAll.  Same problem.  I figured the problem was something like notificationManager going out of scope or something because it blows up on that line.  Not sure what you mean by keeping a handle though... And I don't want to clear the notification when a user selects it, only when a button is clicked in the activity that the user returns to.

Comment: @Metallicraft let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1436/discussion-between-bz-and-metallicraft)

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, but I'll give you credit :).  Answer with: put this `if (notificationManager == null)
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);' before the cancel line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little metalworker told me:
put this `

```
if (notificationManager == null)
  notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

before the cancel line

Comment: So nice for it to be recognized! :)  Hope the rest of the application goes well.